# I Cannot Access My Service From Remote Computer

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, windows-store-apps

Please Guide Me to Resolve my problem.

First, Let me Explain My Program.

I have Created a Service For Balance Check (ie) if You are give input as a Account number, the web service will return the Balance of the Account.

Note: My Client Application is developed in windows store App.

My WebConfig File as Follows:

```
      <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="AccountBalance">
    <endpoint contract="IAccountBalance"
              address="AccountBalance"
              binding="basicHttpBinding">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="AccountBalance/MEX/"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange">
    </endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://192.168.1.8:8081/AccountBalance.svc"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <add scheme="http" port="8081" />
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

</system.serviceModel>
```

I can access the service from Local Computer.
When I deployed it on another machine it is not working.
shows an error:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://:8081/AccountBalance.svc/AccountBalance that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect....

I don't Know Much about the Config. If anything wrong Please Let me know.

I have Hosted my Service in IIS. does any configuration that i have to do in IIS ?

1. I was blocked the Firewall.
2. Both the Systems is in the Same Network.
3. Tried with the System Name too instead of IP.

what else could be the problem? I have found More Number of the Related threads Found here but none of them helped me.

Some of the Threads talking about change the Security From None to Transport. I was tried that too. not worked.

**EDIT 1:**

I was pissed off .. using WPF application i am able to access the service remotely.
why i m not able to access using windows store app.? –
guys help me fast . i m breaking my head on the store app :(

**Answer** :)

Simple, check the **Private Networks(Client & Server)** it is located at **package.appmanifest-> capabilities** :)

Comment: Do you need to do any port forwarding for 8081?

Comment: sorry i didn't get your question ? @NateDiamond

Comment: Sometimes with firewalls and routers you need to use [port forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding) to allow access to specific ports.

Comment: I run this command in command prompt. >netsh http add urlacl url=http://<myIP>:8081/ user=everyone

Comment: @NateDiamond, I blocked the firewall, so, what is the necessary for port forwarding?

Comment: If you are using a router to connect the two machines, you may need to do it from the router administration/settings.

Comment: oh.! anyway, how to do this? any document related to this? @NateDiamond

Comment: It matters on your router. Generally you have to go to 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1 and change the settings. It may be unnecessary though, it was just a thought to see if you'd tried it. Also, is there a reason you're using port 8081 instead of one that is likely to already be forwarded? Also, are you able to get any response from the service from the remote machine, like in a browser?

Comment: @NateDiamond , I tried port forwarding too. not working , I think i m missing some configuration.. :'\

Comment: If you're using security, make sure to change it to `https`.

Comment: Nope i haven't used security, its a testing purpose. @NateDiamond... I was pissed of .. using WPF application its working perfectly... i m able to access the service remotely. why i m not able to access using windows store app.?

Comment: Have you added the internet client capability? Can you access websites or other Uris from the app?

Comment: wow.... thanks a lot @NateDiamond.... u are genius... ya I have not checked the **Private Networks(Client & Server )**.  Now its working perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the `Private Networks (Client and Server) capability` declared in your app manifest.